# Traditional vs Traditionalistic

Tags: difference, suffixes

In general, what are the similarities and differences between two adjectives, the root of which is X, with these forms: X-al vs X-alist vs X-alistic?

What's this phenomenon called? What are the general lessons to be learned?

Some words [on this list] are more easily differentiable, such as global vs globalist, because globalistic refers more to the notion of globalism?

But what about more intricate examples, like dual vs dualistic, and popular vs populist?

Comment: Related: [Why does *-istic* turn some words negative?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189533/why-does-istic-turn-some-words-negative).

Comment: Should the title be changed to "Real" vs. "Realist" vs. "Realistic"?

Comment: @Jasper: Please feel free if better.

Answer (score 2):

As @Dan comments, this issue has been covered on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189533/why-does-istic-turn-some-words-negative). But we can't close cross-site duplicates, so I'll reproduce the essence of [his answer there...](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189535/2637)

> Short answer: it's not the ***istic***, it's the underlying ***ist***, or ultimately ***ism***.

---

Obviously not all ***-isms*** are negative (there's *optimism* as well as *pessimism*). But an awful lot are, and that association carries over to ***-istic*** forms. There's usually a valid "root" form *(simple, traditional)* forcing us ask what "tweak" to the meaning of the root word is intended by ***simplistic, traditionalistic***? By default, unless anything suggests otherwise, we assume the intention is *to disparage an **-ism***.